# How can I have New Line in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline, blazor

I'm trying to create a newline, and having already looked on other forums, some are using '\n',
'\r' or Environment.NewLine but personally nothing works. I give you the code and the result :

1:

```
string n1 = SomeText;
string n2 = AnotherText;
string beforeStr = n1 + Environment.NewLine + n2;
```

2:

```
string n1 = SomeText;
string n2 = AnotherText;
string beforeStr = n1 + '\r' + n2;
```

3:

```
string n1 = SomeText;
string n2 = AnotherText;
string beforeStr = n1 + '\n' + n2;
```

always same result :

```
SomeText AnotherText
```

Comment: You can't. Blazor produces HTML which handles newlines as just whitespace and ignores them. You need to use `div` or `br` elements in the HTML code. YOu can't just create and emit a string though because Blazor (just like all other web stacks) will escape it as eg `&lg;br&gt;`. You should use the proper elements in the *view* of your component and render the text variables in separate `div`s, or separated by `br`

Comment: Blazor is still a web technology working with HTML and Javascript. It won't make HTML work like a console application. What does your component and view look like?

Comment: Ok thank you, I will change the setup structure of my string.

Comment: I use <p>@beforestr</p> into HTML

Comment: Forget the string. It will never work. Why don't you use the Razor view and properties, [like the examples](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/try0)?

Comment: I already know how to use Razor/Blazor, I just have strange case this time...

Comment: It's not strange, it's the expected behavior. It's the same with all web stacks. Even with Webforms, any emitted string is escaped. You *can't* just emit a string and have it appear as HTML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using Razor templates. \r\n, Envirnoment.Newline, and anything else cannot make the compiler budge.

Here is a working solution using Razor Template:

```
<p>@resultString</p>

@code {
    RenderFragment resultString =  @<p>Series not found <br />Error message</p>;
                          
}
```

Update:
You can also use this:

```
MarkupString  resultString = (MarkupString) $"Series not found <br />Error message";
```

Update 2:
From the documents:

> **Render raw HTML** Blazor normally renders strings using DOM text nodes, which means that any markup they may contain will be ignored
> and treated as literal text. This new feature lets you render special
> MarkupString values that will be parsed as HTML or SVG and then
> inserted into the DOM.
>
> WARNING: Rendering raw HTML constructed from any untrusted source is a
> major security risk!
>
> Use the MarkupString type to add blocks of static HTML content.

```
@((MarkupString)myMarkup)

@functions {
    string myMarkup = "<p class='markup'>This is a <em>markup string</em>.</p>";
}
```

Comment: `@((MarkupString) beforeStr.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))` was exactly what i needed. Thank you @enet

Answer (score 21):

The **MarkupString** solution will swallow/interpret all non-escaped html characters. This can lead to a XSS attack with dynamic user input strings.
The way to go here is to html-escape first and then replace all line breaks with <br />

```cshtml
@using System.Web
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

<div>
  @((MarkupString)Regex.Replace(
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@multilineString), "\r?\n|\r", "<br />"))
</div>
```

The regex `\r?\n|\r` will replace `\r (old Mac)`,  `\r\n (Windows)` and `\n (Unix)`

This can also be implemented as a Component.

*MultilineString.razor*

```cshtml
@using System.Web
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

@((MarkupString)Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@Value), "\r?\n|\r", "<br />"))

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Now it's easier to use with `<MultilineString Value=@yourInput />`

Comment: For avoiding NullReferenceExceptions here, you could append `?? string.Empty` after `@Value` in `MultilineString.razor`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very simple solution with CSS:

```css
.pre-wrap {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre-wrap">@MyMultiLineString</div>
```

Comment: Simple and working solution. Before complecating it with components one should try this solution.

Comment: This is incredibly nice and clean. Should be the solution.

Comment: I'm surprised by its simplicity. This should be the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I created a simple component LineBreaksToBRs. It avoids the risks of MarkupString.

```
@if (lines != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        @lines[i];
        <br />
    }

@code {
    string[] lines;

    [Parameter]
    public string InputString { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        lines = InputString?.Split('\n');
    }
}
```

and usage

```
...
<div class="field">
    <span>My Field</span>
    <span>
        <LineBreaksToBRs InputString=@Record.MyField />
    </span>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The document structure in the browser will be in HTML, so you need to be using HTML tags ([`<br />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), specifically) to control the flow of the document.

```
string beforeStr = n1 + '<br />' + n2;
```

As mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos, and presumably because you're using Blazor, you'll probably end up with something like this in your `.razor` component instead:

```
<p>
    @n1 <br /> @n2
</p>
```

Comment: Don't work, ouput is : ``` SomeText<br/>AnotherText ```

Comment: @SoyNeko that's expected - emitted strings are always escaped. You should use the appropriate elements in your component's view

Answer (score 2):

This works pretty good with me

```
@foreach (var sub in beforeStr.Split('\n'))
{
    @sub <br/>
}

@code{
string n1 = SomeText;
string n2 = AnotherText;
string beforeStr = n1 + '\n' + n2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got to work for me.  In my razor file I added this:

```
@foreach (var item in References)
{
    <br />
    @item
}
```

In my C# class I added this:

```
protected List<string> References { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

Just fill in the reference with each line of text you ant and it works great.  I found a lot of other solutions but this was easiest to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at html, and this is what I use to create a new line. There is probably a better way, but this works for me:

```
<div style="display:inline;"> one line</div>
```

Another way for an empty line is:

```
<div style="height:1em;"></div>
```